# How to install molecular 1.1.2 Addon at Linux Blender 2.91

Tags: python, add-on, installation, linux

In Blender 2.91 on Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.10.6-051006-generic) I can not install the Addon Molecular from: https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases
It works fine in Windows 10 with Blender 2.91.

The problem might be something missig in python, but I don't know how to fix it.
I found this line migh be giving a hint on the problem: https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/blob/60385f589d3d31261cfb51802a915dd0355d500c/make_release.py#L29

> #TODO, blenders (or a compatible) python bin needs to be in $PATH, and if you use blender's you need to copy the python includes from SVN
> #into the include folder of blenders python, too

[image: Molecular Error Message]

The Blender system info says Python 3.7 is in place:

```
=====================================
```

## = Blender 2.91.0 System Information =

## Blender:

```
version: 2.91.0, branch: master, commit date: 2020-11-25 08:34, hash: 0f45cab862b8, type: Release
build date: 2020-11-25, 08:51:08
platform: Linux
binary path: '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/blender'
build cflags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -fuse-ld=gold -std=gnu11   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
build cxxflags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -fuse-ld=gold -std=c++17   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
build linkflags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/sources/buildbot-worker-linux_centos7/linux_291/blender.git/source/creator/blender.map'
build system: CMake
```

## Python:

```
version: 3.7.7 (default, Jul  9 2020, 12:52:49)  [GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogateescape
paths:
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/startup'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/python/lib/python37.zip'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/python/lib/python3.7'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/freestyle/modules'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/addons/modules'
    '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/scripts/addons/modules'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/addons'
    '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/scripts/addons'

Python (External Binary):
=====================================

binary path: '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/python/bin/python3.7m'
version: Python 3.7.7
```

## Directories:

```
scripts:
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules'
    '/home/p/3d/blender/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts'
    '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/scripts'
user scripts: '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/scripts'
pref scripts: None
datafiles: '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/datafiles'
config: '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/config'
scripts : '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/scripts'
autosave: '/home/p/.config/blender/2.91/autosave'
tempdir: '/tmp/blender_Yjx2oy/'
```

Comment: Maybe @scorpion81 himself could give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scorpion81 did a new build local and uploaded a new version. Now I can install the addon and it works as expected.

[link to the github page](https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases/tag/1.1.2b)